# Multer req.file showing undefined - NodeJS | VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, express, multer

So, for my recent project I used multer for file upload as every youtuber was suggesting that.But even after I define all the functions correctly, req.file is always showing undefined.

**booking_route.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const multer = require('multer');

//Storage
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (request, file, callback) {
       callback(null, './public/uploads/images')
    },
    filename: function (request, file, callback) {
       callback(null, Date.now() + file.originalname)
    }
 })

 //Upload Params
 const upload = multer({
     storage: storage,
     limits: {
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 3
     }
 })

 const { bookHallForEvent } = 
  require('../controllers/booking_controller')


  router.post('/events', upload.single('image'), bookHallForEvent)

  module.exports = router
```

**booking_controller.js**

```
const eventModel = require('../models/event_model')

const bookHallForEvent = async (req, res) => {
   try {
    console.log(req.file);
    const { hallID, timeSlot, date, name, description, username } = 
     req.body;
    const oldEvent = await eventModel.findOne({ hall_id: hallID, date: 
    date, time_slot: timeSlot })
    if (oldEvent) {
        res.status(400).json({
            error: "Event already booked in the same date and timeslot 
     for this venue"
        })
        } else {
        const event = await eventModel.create({
            name,
            description,
            date,
            time_slot: timeSlot,
            hall_id: hallID,
            user_id: username
          })
        res.status(201).json({
            event_res: event
        })
            }
         } catch (err) {
         console.log(err);
        }

           }

         module.exports = {
      bookHallForEvent
       }
```

**IndividualHallView.vue**

```
<form
        @submit.prevent="handleBooking"
        method="POST"
        enctype="multipart/form-data"
      >
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="BatsmanLabel" class="form-label">Event name</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              v-model="bookingData.event_name"
              id="NameInput"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="BowlerLabel" class="form-label"
              >Event Description</label
            >
            <textarea
              class="form-control"
              id="exampleFormControlTextarea1"
              v-model="bookingData.event_desc"
              rows="3"
            ></textarea>
          </div>

          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="DateInput" class="form-label">Date</label>
            <input
              type="date"
              v-model="bookingData.event_date"
              class="form-control"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="formFileMultiple" class="form-label"
              >Add one or more images</label
            >
            <input
              class="form-control"
              type="file"
              name="image"
              id="formFileMultiple"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="TimeSlotInput" class="form-label">Time slots</label>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input
                class="form-check-input"
                type="checkbox"
                value="8AM - 9AM"
                id="flexCheckDefault"
                v-model="bookingData.event_timeslots"
              />
              <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                8AM - 9AM
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input
                class="form-check-input"
                type="checkbox"
                value="9AM - 10AM"
                id="flexCheckDefault"
                v-model="bookingData.event_timeslots"
              />
              <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                9AM - 10AM
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input
                class="form-check-input"
                type="checkbox"
                value="10AM - 11AM"
                id="flexCheckDefault"
                v-model="bookingData.event_timeslots"
              />
              <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                10AM - 11AM
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input
                class="form-check-input"
                type="checkbox"
                value="11AM - 12PM"
                id="flexCheckDefault"
                v-model="bookingData.event_timeslots"
              />
              <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                11AM - 12PM
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input
                class="form-check-input"
                type="checkbox"
                value="12PM - 1PM"
                id="flexCheckDefault"
                v-model="bookingData.event_timeslots"
              />
              <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                12PM - 1PM
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input
                class="form-check-input"
                type="checkbox"
                value="1PM - 2PM"
                id="flexCheckDefault"
                v-model="bookingData.event_timeslots"
              />
              <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                1PM - 2PM
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input
                class="form-check-input"
                type="checkbox"
                value="2PM - 3PM"
                id="flexCheckDefault"
                v-model="bookingData.event_timeslots"
              />
              <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                2PM - 3PM
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-secondary"
            data-bs-dismiss="modal"
          >
            Cancel
          </button>
          <button data-bs-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary">
            Submit
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

I really hope that it is a small bug that's causing this

P.S sorry for the bad code formatting

Comment: Without your `handleBooking` Vue method, this is impossible to answer

Comment: It doesn't make sense to treat the system as black box. You need to isolate the problem to either front or back end. This is easily done by checking a request in devtools, and this is done on your side

Comment: @Phil handleBooking just calls the bookingHallForEvent method from booking_controller.js

Comment: @ManoSanjay I guarantee that it does not because `handleBooking` is client-side and `bookingHallForEvent` is server-side. Please [edit] your question to show the code for the `handleBooking` **client-side Vue method**

Answer (score 0):

In order to send a `multipart/form-data` request that Multer can interpret, you need to construct a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object.

This code will capture your file input as well as all the inputs backed by `bookingData` models

```js
methods: {
  async handleBooking({ target }) {
    // capture all the named inputs in your <form>, namely
    // <input type="file" name="image" />
    const data = new FormData(target);

    // now add your other form data
    data.append("name", this.bookingData.event_name);
    data.append("description", this.bookingData.event_desc);
    data.append("date", this.bookingData.event_date);
    // etc

    try {
      const res = await fetch("/api/events", {
        // just guessing the URL here
        method: "POST",
        body: data,
      });

      if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error(`${res.status}: ${await res.text()}`);
      }

      const { event_res } = await res.json();

      // do something with event_res, eg
      console.log("event created", event_res);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("handleBooking", err);
    }
  }
}
```

If you're using Axios instead of `fetch`, the relevant part would look like this...

```js
try {
  const { data: { event_res } } = await axios.post("/api/events", data);
  // do something with event_res, eg
  console.log("event created", event_res);
} catch (err) {
  console.error("handleBooking", err.toJSON());
}
```